# How to add a windows to a login server

Tags: windows, authentication, active-directory

I work as an it intern in a college, and i need to format and add a windows machine to their network, but it needs to have the "login" screen so you can input your login info and login to our server.
ive put the machine on our domain, but it didnt help.

The machine is a W10 one.

EDIT:
I rejoined the domain and is now working as intended.
i'm sorry

Comment: If a machine joined a domain you have to enter username and password to log into the machine. So could you try to provide a little more information about what doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: If there's no login screen, then what *does* happen when you turn on the computer?